# which DataIdentifier (DID) I need to get the voltage from ECU?

Tags: python, can-bus, automotive, uds

I use IsoTPSocketConnection of UDS protocol, I want to get the voltage from the vehicleת I wrote (I show part of the code):

```
with Client(conn, request_timeout=2, config=config) as client:
    response = client.read_data_by_identifier([0xF190])
```

bat I don't know which DID to put (hex)

Answer (score 0):

ISO 14229-1 defines a list of common data identifier and there is no data identifier for battery voltage ­– this is entirely vendor specific.

OBD2 adapters usually come with an API to read the voltage at the OBD2 socket.